# Issues implementing password_hash in PHP

Tags: php, passwords, php-password-hash

I've read a few posts with how to implement password_hash() and have tried to give this a go.

When I run my code without the hashing, it works fine but when I add in the hashing function I run in to trouble.

By trouble, I mean the page just goes blank and nothing is stored in to the DB.

Here is the code relating to the hashing and entry in to DB

```
//Hasing of pw 
$hash = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


//Creation of member
$query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO `members` ( `Username`, `Email`, `Password`, `Activation`) VALUES ( '$name', '$Email', '$hash', '$activation')";
```

$Password here is the plaintext password collected from the page.

I can't see what is causing the issue.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `$hash` returned from `password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.41-0+deb7u1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blank page probably is caused by the lack of enabled error reporting.

The functions [password_hash](http://php.net/password_hash) and [password_verify](http://php.net/password_verify) requires PHP version 5.5.0 to work.

Using a PHP version below that causes your script to fail.

Comment: This is so obvious. I just realized my version doesn't line up

Answer (score 0):

The function `password_hash` and `password_verify` requires PHP version 5.5.0 to work.

If you are using `PHP version 5.5.0` then Try

```
echo $hash; exit();
```

To Verify Password of password hash. You have to use `password_verify` function to verify passwords.

`password_verify` Verifies that the given hash matches the given password.

**Note that** `password_hash()` returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part of the returned hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the verify function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

[Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: This doesn't remotely answer the question. At all.

Comment: I would use password_verify on login page, not on register.

Comment: @James yes. Use it on log in page.

Comment: @Hassan, read the question again. Your answer doesn't remotely answer the question.

Comment: @Repox Sorry, I did not read the question correctly. I have updated my answer. Could you please remove vote down from my answer.